# Excel to JSON - need help modifying

Tags: json, excel, vba

I know this question has been beaten to death, and I'm sorry for asking, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring this out. So I found a code that does what I want about 90% of the way, there is only two problems. I have to format the excel sheet as a table, and the outputted data is hard to read. I have tried to modify it, but have failed miserably, so here I am for help.
so here's what I'm trying to do:

1: change it so I don't have to format the sheet as a table, and it converts a range while keeping it so that the first row A1, B1..etc are the headers.

2: print it out vertical instead of horizontal

Here's the code I've been messing with

```vb
Private Sub export_in_json_format_Click()

    Dim fs As Object

    Dim jsonfile
    Dim rangetoexport As Range
    Dim rowcounter As Long
    Dim columncounter As Long
    Dim linedata As String
   
    ' change range here
    Set rangetoexport = Sheet1.Range("A1:J58")
   
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' change dir here
   
    Set jsonfile = fs.CreateTextFile("Desktop" & "Testr.json", True)
   
    linedata = "{""Output"": ["
    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    For rowcounter = 2 To rangetoexport.Rows.Count
        linedata = ""
        For columncounter = 1 To rangetoexport.Columns.Count
            linedata = linedata & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(1, columncounter) & """" & ":" & """" & rangetoexport.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter) & """" & ","
        Next
        linedata = Left(linedata, Len(linedata) - 1)
        If rowcounter = rangetoexport.Rows.Count Then
            linedata = "{" & linedata & "}"
        Else
            linedata = "{" & linedata & "},"
        End If
       
        jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    Next
    linedata = "]}"
    jsonfile.WriteLine linedata
    jsonfile.Close

    Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

and it exports out as this

[image]

so as you hopefully can see it goes ID:#, Name:#,...etc
what i have been trying to do is:

```
ID1
Name
Price
Quantity

ID1
Name
Price
Quantity
```

I have found bits and pieces, but can't seem to get it all to work out without throwing errors left, and right. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. sorry about the code, for some reason its not pasting right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "pretty print" formatting you can do something like this:

```vb
Sub testJson()
    Debug.Print "{""Output"":" & TableToJsonArray([A1:C4]) & "}"
End Sub


Function TableToJsonArray(tbl As Range)
    Dim rv As String, sep, sep2, arr, r As Long, c As Long, itm As String
    arr = tbl.Value
    rv = "[" & vbCrLf
    For r = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        sep2 = ""
        itm = "  {" & vbCrLf
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            itm = itm & sep2 & "    """ & arr(1, c) & """:""" & arr(r, c) & """"
            sep2 = "," & vbCrLf
        Next c
        rv = rv & sep & itm & vbCrLf & "  }"
        sep = "," & vbCrLf
    Next r
    TableToJsonArray = rv & vbCrLf & "]"
End Function
```

Output:

```json
{"Output":[
  {
    "Col1":"blah",
    "Col2":"blah",
    "Col3":"blah"
  },
  {
    "Col1":"blah",
    "Col2":"blah",
    "Col3":"blah"
  },
  {
    "Col1":"blah",
    "Col2":"blah",
    "Col3":"blah"
  }
]}
```

Probably better to use the VBA-JSON library for this though.

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON